# Get all subscribers with same last name via MailChimp API

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

I have used this library to Add, Delete, and Update subscribers in MailChimp list via my PHP application. **https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api**

It is possible to retrieve all the subscribers from a list, but I couln't find a way to get all the subscribers with the same last name from the list.

Is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `FNAME` and `LNAME` fields on a list member are technically MailChimp `merge_fields` and cannot be queried via the API. You can retrieve the full list of members and then filter the results in PHP.

Reference the API documentation for the `list/members` endpoint:
https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#read-get_lists_list_id_members

Comment: We can add a custom field to MailChimp list. Let's assume we add a field called "key". So we can add same "key" to multiple people. So, it's not a merge_field. Then is there a way to find people who has the same "key" ? I need to get the number of subscribers who have the same "key".